# Adding a DLL reference to a VS 2008 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reference

I have a vs 2008 solution that has 2 projects. One references the other one, but I need to add a DLL to one of the projects. I go to the solution explorere, right click and go to Add Reference. It gives me 2 tabs: Project and SQL Server.

In Project, I see my other project and added that in. SQL Server is blank. But how do I add just a single DLL?

Answer (score 3):

You must be creating a SQL Server project. To add a DLL reference in SQL Server project, you must first register that dll with sql server. How to register a dll with SQL SERVER ?
Look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005) tutorial on codeproject. Once dll is registered, it will be available for reference in SQL Server tab.